# Gradle - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to run a very simple project using Gradle and running into the following error when using the `gradlew run command`:

> could not find or load main class 'hello.HelloWorld'

Here is my file structure:

```
SpringTest
    -src
        -hello
            -HelloWorld.java
            -Greeter.java
    -build
         -libs
         -tmp
    -gradle
         -wrapper
    -build.gradle
    -gradlew
    -gradlew.bat
```

I excluded the contents of the libs and tmp folders because I didn't think that would be relevant information for this issue, but I can add it in if need be.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

mainClassName = 'hello/HelloWorld'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
}

jar {
    baseName = "gs-gradle"
    version = "0.1.0"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?  I've tried all sorts of things for the `mainClassName` attribute but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does not applying `application` also implicitly applies `java` plug-in?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I see two problems here, one with `sourceSet` another with `mainClassName`.

1. Either move java source files to `src/main/java` instead of just `src`. Or set `sourceSet` properly by adding the following to build.gradle.

   ```
   sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
   ```
2. `mainClassName` should be fully qualified class name, not path.

   ```
   mainClassName = "hello.HelloWorld"
   ```

Comment: Where do I change sourceSets?  In my build.gradle file?  Or is there a configuration file that I need to change?

Comment: When I add `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']` I get an error in the jar task

Comment: `MissingPropertyException: Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName'` for Gradlew 4.1

Comment: @fuat you need to have the application plugin

Comment: `Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName' for root project` error. Please show full build.gradle file

Answer (score 35):

Modify build.gradle to put your main class in the manifest:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'hello.helloWorld'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

I just ran into this problem and decided to debug it myself since i couldn't find a solution on the internet. 
All i did is change the mainClassName to it's whole path(with the correct subdirectories in the project ofc)

```
    mainClassName = 'main.java.hello.HelloWorld'
```

I know it's been almost one year since the post has been made, but i think someone will find this information useful.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 10):

Just to make it clear for newbies trying to run a gradle project from Netbeans:
To understand this, you need to see what the main class name looks like **and** what the gradle build looks like:

Main class:

```
package com.stormtrident;

public class StormTrident {
    public static void main(String[] cmdArgs) {
    }
}
```

Notice that it is part of the package "com.stormtrident".

Gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

defaultTasks 'jar'

jar {
 from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }    
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.stormtrident.StormTrident'
    }
}


sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.stormtrident.StormTrident'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //---apache storm
    compile 'org.apache.storm:storm-core:1.0.0'  //compile 
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}
```

Comment: For me, adding your jar { manifest { attributes } } bit helped. Thanks!

Comment: What is Netbeans doing differently that Gradle seems to be ran differently?  I am attempting this manually so I can understand Gradle better.  Netbeans seems to be really good at Maven, but Gradle seems to be fragile in Netbeans.

Answer (score 4):

For Netbeans 11 users, this works for me:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

// This comes out to package + '.' + mainClassName
mainClassName = 'com.hello.JavaApplication1'
```

Here generally is my tree:

```
C:\...\NETBEANSPROJECTS\JAVAAPPLICATION1
│   build.gradle
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───hello
│   │                   JavaApplication1.java
│   │
│   └───test
│       └───java
└───test
```

Answer (score 3):

Struggled with the same problem for some time. But after creating the directory structure src/main/java and putting the source(from the top of the package), it worked as expected.

The [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) I tried with. After you execute `gradle build`, you will have to be able to find `classes` under `build` directory.

Comment: Also, since no one else is specifying it: the `build.gradle` file has to be located "alongside" the `src/` directory, not along with the .java files in `src/main/java/hello/`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by running a clean of by gradle build (or delete the gradle build folder mannually)

This occurs if you move the main class to a new package and the old main class is still referenced in the claspath

Comment: build/clean + build/build does build build doesn't fix the runtime issue

Comment: Deleting build saved my life after renaming part of the src tree. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you decided to write your `hello.World` class in Kotlin, another issue might be that you have to reference it as `mainClassName = "hello.WorldKt"`.

src/main/java/hello/World.kt:

```
package hello
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ...
}
// class World {} // this line is not necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

In my build.gradle, I resolved this issue by creating a task and then specifying the "mainClassName" as follows:

```
task(runSimpleXYZProgram, group: 'algorithms', description: 'Description of what your program does', dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    mainClassName = 'your.entire.package.classContainingYourMainMethod'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, it was because **I didn't have my class in a package**. Put your `HelloWorld.java` file in a "package" folder. You may have to create a new package folder:

Right click on the `hello` folder and select "New" > "Package". Then give it a name (e.g: com.example) and move your `HelloWorld.java` class into the package.

Answer (score 0):

1. verify if *gradle.properties* define right one JAVA_HOVE

   org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

or

2. if it's not defined be sure if Eclipse know JDK and not JRE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding below code to my application.

//    enter code here
this is error I was getting when I run build.gradle.  main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Comment: That's already the entry point for a springboot project to start and the question is about configuration conflicts not how to initiate a project

Answer (score 0):

For a project structure like

```
project_name/src/main/java/Main_File.class
```

in the file `build.gradle`, add the following line

```
mainClassName = 'Main_File'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please edit your question and elaborate a bit on why your solution is working, i.e. what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Need full build.gradle file as an example

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Boot, this might be the issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2489.

Basically, the output directories changed in Gradle 4.0, so if you have them hardcoded the execution will fail.

The solution is to replace:

```
bootRun {
   dependsOn pathingJar
   doFirst {
      classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", pathingJar.archivePath)
   }
}
```

by:

```
bootRun {
   dependsOn pathingJar
   doFirst {
      classpath = files(sourceSets.main.output.files, pathingJar.archivePath)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add `String[] args` inside main method `public static void main()`

After changing it to `public static void main(String[] args)`, everything worked.

My `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'hugo.HelloWorld'
```

[image: FOld stru]

Answer (score 0):

For [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts) use this code:

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "my.package.name.MyClassName"
    // ...
}
```

Another similar notation:

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "my.package.name.MyClassName"
    }
    // ...
}
```