# How to use a Java main class on a Kotlin Spring Project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

Due to some circumstances I had to change the Kotlin main class in my Spring Boot project to Java. But when I build the project with Gradle i get an error:
`Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved`

I fixed the building problem by setting `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']` as stated in [Gradle - Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924932/gradle-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) but this messes up some things locally(Can't see Kotlin package in IntelliJ which includes the whole source code).
I suspect there is a better way to setup a Kotlin project with a Java main class.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `mainClassName` property?

Add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
    mainClassName = "com.my-package.my-another-package.MyMainClass"
```

Also, make sure you apply `java` plugin:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
```