# Could not find or load main class in Eclipse Run/Debug as after adding firebase-admin to build.gradle of Spring Boot App

Tags: eclipse, firebase, spring-boot, gradle, jhipster

I have a Spring Boot App generated by JHipster. It works fine but after adding the firebase-admin dependency in the Gradle build file I cannot run or debug this application in Eclipse. 
`The error is 'Could not find or load main class' caused by 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'`. 
The missing class is the annotated SpringBootApplication class I'm clicking on in Eclipse.

The application runs if I start Gradle from the command line or Eclipse or deploy the app to the cloud but without 'Debug as' in Eclipse I cannot use hot code replacement for development.

When I remove the dependency the 'Run/Debug as' in Eclipse works fine. I need this dependency to connect to the Firebase Firestore.

Comment: What is your version of `firebase-admin` dependency inside `build.gradle` file? I'd recommend to change to the latest which includes all necessary stuff. Moreover, try to update Spring dependencies to the `4.0` versions and higher.

Comment: the `firebase-admin` dependency is the newest `6.12.0`, the `spring-boot` dependencies are `2.1.11` and `spring-core` is `5.1.12`, all from Dec. 2019, so up to date, the project is created with the newest JHipster generator so they should not be outdated dependencies

Comment: if you change `spring-boot` version to [2.2.0 or 2.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot) instead of `2.1.11` and `spring-core` version to [5.2.0 or 5.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core) instead of `5.1.12`, are you facing the same issue? Did you try to use [6.8.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin) version of `firebase-admin`?

Comment: no changes, I think Spring itself is not the problem, I'm wondering why this  single dependency (`firebase-admin`) is causing this issue in Eclipse

Comment: What is your [JDK/JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090885/8370915) version? I've found some answers related to similar Eclipse issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695199/8370915) and [here w/ maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406127/8370915), but still. Also try to play w/ configuration inside `build.gradle file` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24924932/8370915).

Comment: As suggested in the JHipster documentation I'm using a ´AdoptOpenJDK 11´ and also tried it with an ´Oracle JDK 8´.
Also played a lot with the ´build.gradle´ but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Comment: Could you add, please, your full `build.gradle` file to your question and [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That would be helpful.

Comment: The `build.gradle` is publicly available at [github](https://github.com/mathias-schulze/kicker-app/blob/master/build.gradle). You also find the hole project there. Because it's initially generated there's a lot of source code.

Comment: I suppose your particular problem was because of incorrect configuration inside IDE Eclipse and it wasn't related to the code, rather to the launch settings of this project while importing. Because I don't have such error just NPE while running this project because of [nonexistent file](https://github.com/mathias-schulze/kicker-app/blob/master/src/main/java/de/msz/kickerapp/service/FirestoreService.java#L53) by this [path](https://github.com/mathias-schulze/kicker-app/tree/master/src/main/resources). But I'm using Intelij IDEA as IDE.