# Error trying to start a JDA Discord Bot on VPS

Tags: java, bots

So,
I created this JDA bot, and now i want to start it on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 VPS...
On IntelliJ Idea I used "gradlew build" and i created a jar file, so I put it on my VPS.

I did:
"sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless"

Then I created a folder called "bot" and I put the jar file in "bot" folder.
So I entered the folder and I used:

"java -jar JavaBotJDA11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

But there's an error:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.project.MainClass

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.project.MainClass

Comment: You didn't include your main class in the jar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not set the main class in your project. I'm not sure how it works for gradle, but I'm sure something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924932/gradle-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) should help you.