# With the new update of JDA 4.2.0 the new built JAR file on the VPS returns NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gradle, discord-jda

With the new update of [JDA 4.2.0](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/releases) trying to run the jar file on the VPS fails.
I have tried various options, such as

- [creating a fat jar](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar)
- searching for other similar issues

  - [source 1](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/issues/267)
  - [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924932/gradle-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Yet none of these options seemed to work, since the VPS console output stays unchanged:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/hooks/ListenerAdapter
```

So my current question is, what should my `gradle.build` look like, or is this a problem of the VPS not refreshing correctly? Or perhaps another problem I'm not aware of.

As for what my `gradle.build` looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

group '...'
version '2.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter(
    )
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.2.0_168'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
    compile 'com.vdurmont:emoji-java:5.1.1'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': '...'
        )
    }
}
```

NOTE: In the previous snapshot of `1.0-SNAPSHOT` this following `gradle.build` worked to start up the project:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group '...'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:3.5.0_329'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
    compile 'com.vdurmont:emoji-java:5.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `build.gradle` to build a working shadow jar:

```
plugins {
  id 'application' // this allows you to set a mainClassName
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.0.0' // this adds the shadowJar task
}

group '...'
version '2.0-SNAPSHOT'
mainClassName = 'your main class goes here' // this sets the main class property in your manifest automatically

repositories {
    jcenter() // jcenter is a superset of mavenCentral
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.2.0_191'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
    compile 'com.vdurmont:emoji-java:5.1.1'
}
```

Run the `shadowJar` gradle task to compile your jar file. This will then be placed inside `build/libs` and has the format `[name]-all.jar`. Do not forget to replace the `mainClassName` with the fully qualified name of your main class.

Comment: Hello Minn, I tried your method, yet I don't fully understand what you mean with "Run the shadowJar gradle task to compile your jar file." as I am not familiar with shadowJar.

Comment: figured it out and works like a charm! :D thanks for the help!