# how to create executable java gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, discord-jda

[image]
this is my build.gradle

[image]
this is what happens when i attempt to run the built jar.

```
 plugins {
    id 'java'
}


group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation "net.dv8tion:JDA:5.0.0-alpha.6"
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation"io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.1.0"

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'bullshitPackage.main'
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With the new update of JDA 4.2.0 the new built JAR file on the VPS returns NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426422/with-the-new-update-of-jda-4-2-0-the-new-built-jar-file-on-the-vps-returns-nocla)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the shadowjar plugin to include all dependencies in your jar.

To use it in your build.gradle file, try:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:7.0.0"
    }
} 
 
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.0.0'
}



group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation "net.dv8tion:JDA:5.0.0-alpha.6"
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation"io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.1.0"

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'bullshitPackage.main'
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Then from your console, navigate to your project's root folder that contains the file `gradlew`, then run `gradlew shadowjar` to build the jar into the `./build/libs` folder.