# Java + Gradle : Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to build and run a java project using Gradle.
The project building succeeded. However, the error "Could not find or load main class ~" has occurred when running it.
I found and tried a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924932/gradle-could-not-find-or-load-main-class). But the solution didn't work.

My project structure is here.

```
javaAddressRecorder
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── main
│   │           ├── DbAddressRecorder.class
│   │           ├── Geth.class
│   │           └── JavaAddressRecorder.class
│   ├── generated
│   │   └── sources
│   │       ├── annotationProcessor
│   │       │   └── java
│   │       │       └── main
│   │       └── headers
│   │           └── java
│   │               └── main
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── JavaAddressRecorder-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       │   └── previous-compilation-data.bin
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── DbAddressRecorder.java
    │   │   ├── Geth.java
    │   │   └── JavaAddressRecorder.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        └── resources
```

And my `build.gradle` file is here.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
    implementation 'org.web3j:core:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.5'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'JavaAddressRecorder'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}
```

The `src/main/java/JavaAddressRecorder.java` has `main()` and doesn't have package name. The `src/main/java/DbAddressRecorder.java` and `src/main/java/Geth.java` are used from the `main()`.
So the `./gradlew build` works without any errors, but `java -jar JavaAddressRecorder-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` doesn't work with the error below.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class JavaAddressRecorder
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaAddressRecorder
```

I confirmed the `JavaAddressRecorder` is included the jar file like below.

```bash
******@****** libs % jar tf javaAddressRecorder-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep JavaAddressRecorder.class
JavaAddressRecorder.class
```

I'm a newbie to the Java language.
Anyone who knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA
OS: MacOS 11.6.8
Java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.5+9-LTS-191)
Gradle: 7.5.1

*Add META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from the .jar file*

```
******** META-INF % cat MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JavaAddressRecorder
```

Comment: has `JavaAddressRecorder` a main method?

Comment: Can you please add the contents of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from the JAR file to the question?

Comment: You can use the [Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/application_plugin.html) to specify a main class.

Comment: The `JavaAddressRecorder` has a main method.
I added the contents of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from the JAR file to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that uses the shadowJar.
The `build.gradle` is here.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id ("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
    implementation 'org.web3j:core:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.5'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "JavaAddressRecorder"
}
```

And run

```bash
./gradlew shadowJar
```